# Youtube iFrame embed throws TypeError 'Undefined' in Safari for Flash Player and Freezes Page

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe, youtube

The following error occurs in Safari (6.1) when embedding the iFrame (using JavaScript library):
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.b.getVideoData().video_id')
    ib (www-embed-player-vflMNvKDU.js, line 149)
    (anonymous function)
    q (www-embed-player-vflMNvKDU.js, line 15)
    (anonymous function) (www-embed-player-vflMNvKDU.js, line 73)

These errors continue to be thrown one after another indefinitely and cause the page to freeze up.

These errors are not seen in any other browser. The same exact page does not throw errors in Safari 6.1 that is running HTML5. This only happens when the Youtube iFrame tries to run the flash player in Safari 6.1 (btw, youtube flash videos work fine on youtube.com on my local machine).

Finally, the 5 videos do successfully load as the onReady event is fired for each of them

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm also having this issue but only in some versions of Safari 7? Did you find a resolution?